# how to directly convert wxpython image to pyplot image without saving

Tags: image, matplotlib, wxpython

I am trying to display a wxpython screen shot in pyplot but I dont want to save the image.
this is what I have

```py
import wx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
thisApp = wx.App( redirect=False )  
def saveSnapshot(dcSource): #takes arg dcSource
    # based largely on code posted to wxpython-users by Andrea Gavana 2006-11-08
    size = dcSource.Size
    bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(size.width, size.height)
    memDC = wx.MemoryDC()
    memDC.SelectObject(bmp)
    memDC.Blit( 0, 0, size.width, size.height, dcSource, 0, 0)
    memDC.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
    img = bmp.ConvertToImage()
    img.SaveFile('saved.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
    img = mpimg.imread('saved.png')
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
saveSnapshot(wx.ScreenDC())
```

this is something like what I want, basically not to save the file just display it.

```
    img = bmp.ConvertToImage()
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `BytesIO` object. A possible solution would be:

```py
import wx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
thisApp = wx.App(redirect=False)

def saveSnapshot(dcSource):
    size = dcSource.Size
    bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(size.width, size.height)
    memDC = wx.MemoryDC()
    memDC.SelectObject(bmp)
    memDC.Blit( 0, 0, size.width, size.height, dcSource, 0, 0)
    memDC.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
    img = bmp.ConvertToImage()
    bio = BytesIO()
    bs = wx.OutputStream(bio)
    img.SaveStream(bs, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
    bio.seek(0) #rewind stream
    plt.imshow(plt.imread(bio))
    plt.show()

saveSnapshot(wx.ScreenDC())
```

I found some ideas for this approach [here](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.6/recipes.html#capturing-to-a-pil-image).

**Update:**
A slightly different approach using [pyscreenshot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot) could look like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

def saveSnapshot():
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks that worked, but it didn't give me the time saving I was looking for it. it is only 0.003s faster. The link has some good information I will study it, and maybe find a more efficient way to capture and display screen shots. I was using it to make a video of screen captures it works good but I only get a frame rate of 8frames per second. I was hoping I could get it up to 15.

Comment: You may have a look at pyscreenshot (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot) which might be faster.

Comment: thank you, that is perfect. I timed pyscreenshots to be almost 10times faster than the method I was using. Your right, I should have written a better original question both answers were very helpful as I try and learn more about image processing :)